# W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out

Tags: java, android, sockets, heroku

I am trying to connect to a Node server app on Heroku :

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.send('Hello World');
})

var server = app.listen(PORT, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port

   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

However, it always times out :

```
    SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
09-01 03:24:43.813 24507-25053/myapp.ca.my_init_application W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
```

Changing the target server to Google.com doesn't help either.

**Android**

```
private void sendMessage(final String msg) {

        final String serverName = "myapp-node-js.herokuapp.com";

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {

                    Socket clientSocket = new Socket(serverName, new ServerSocket(0).getLocalPort());

                    OutputStream out = clientSocket.getOutputStream();

                    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);

                    output.println(msg);
                    output.flush();
                    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                    final String st = input.readLine();

                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            if (st.trim().length() != 0)
                                Log.v("MyApp", "\nFrom Server : " + st);
                        }
                    });

                    output.close();
                    out.close();
                    clientSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();
    }
```

Why is the connection unsuccessful?

I have the internet options set up :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The socket has not been bound yet so if you try this `new ServerSocket(0).getLocalPort();` then it will return `-1`. you need to keep the symmetry interns of port number so use

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket(serverName,5000);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Pavneet_Singh. Nothing changes. Still timing out.

Comment: you sure that you are using the correct domain name, can you try it with IP address

Comment: Yes. The app is [HERE at rev-node-js](https://rev-node-js.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: I am getting this exception `java.net.UnknownHostException: myapp-node-js.herokuapp.com` the issue is with the host name

Comment: How do I fix it?

Comment: I tired it, seems like the request is being redirected many times, maybe this might help to get a static ip or address https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/fixie